How to format variable output from a JSON in PowerBI (Fabric) Pipeline Variable Activity
I am creating a Fabric Pipeline in PowerBI that queries an Azure Data Explorer (ADX) table and returns a single column with thousands of rows (Using a lookup step).  Then the pipeline puts the lookup output into a variable (Variable Step).   The problem I have is that I cannot select the values only.  Everything I have tried either results in only returning the first row or I get the column name and value (as opposed to only the value.  Here is example of what the output from the lookup step looks like:

I would like to pass this output to a variable that results in the following:
Example output: 11111111, 22222222

I have tried using the following expressions neither have the correct result:
@string(activity('Lookup').output.value.Col1

'Col1' not recognized

@string(activity('Lookup').output.value

Returns {"Col1":11111111}, {"Col2":22222222}

How can I get the correct format for my variable output?

You can write the expression for the variable as below to get the output as expected.
@replace(replace(replace(replace(string(activity('Lookup1').output.value),'{"col1":"',''),'"}',''),'[',''),']','')

This expression converts the output of the lookup activity to string and then removes the substrings {"col1":",  "}, [,] from them.
Lookup activity output:

Variable output:

